# Use MapControllerRoute and MapGet together in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

In the ASP.NET Core project, I had just a few endpoints that do simple tasks.

Forexample `/` endpoint will redirect to `/.well-known/agent-configuration`, and it worked fine.

```
endpoints.MapGet("/", context =>
{
    context.Response.Redirect("/.well-known/agent-configuration", permanent: false);
    return System.Threading.Tasks.Task.CompletedTask;
});
```

Now, I add a few controllers, and when I used the `MapControllerRoute` to route on endpoints to functions in controllers, the `MapGet` will redirect to `/` endpoint to `/.well-known/agent-configuration` page, but show the `page can’t be found`.

```
endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "api/v1/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you set the route template with `api/v1` prefix by default, route `/.well-known/agent-configuration` does not apply to this routing rule.

You can change the route to `api/v1/.well-known/agent-configuration`. Or add one more routing convention:

```
endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
```

You can have a try.

Comment: After changing the routing convention, by removing the `api/v1`, same issue "page not found".

Comment: Can you share your directory structure? @Stavrogin